# Masstransit Automatonymous :Discarding events on missing sagas instances going to error queue

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

Automatonymous using Redis : Same event is used by multiple state machines Sagas.When the event is published (Fan out), The sagas which are not expecting the event and  using x.OnMissingInstance(x=>x.Discard()), the published event is going to Error Queue. I was expecting it to just ignore without putting it to error queue. Please clarify

Comment: Please post the code to help understand the problem. OnMissingInstance will discard if told to, unless an instance already exists and the message is not accepted in the instance's current state.

Comment: Hello Chris, found out that x.OnMissingInstance(x=>x.Discard()) is working for in-memory repository but not with Redis repository.For testing purpose, i commented my redis repository which is passed to Statemachine configuration (  e.StateMachineSaga(saga, redisRepository);) and used inmemory and it started working. Is there a way onMissingInstance discard will work with Redis as well ?

Comment: Also when using Redis, getting an error "The state is not defined for the Saga state machine" when actually the saga is not expecting the event.

Comment: For live support, you should join the MassTransit discord: https://masstransit-project.com/discord.html